# How to stop "loop.run_forever()" with "loop.stop()" in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, event-loop

I'm trying to stop [**loop.run_forever()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_forever) with [**loop.stop()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.stop) in Python as shown below but [**loop.stop()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.stop) doesn't stop [**loop.run_forever()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_forever):

```py
import asyncio

async def test():
    print("Test")

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

loop.create_task(test())

loop.run_forever()
loop.stop() # Here
```

The documentation says about [**loop.run_forever()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_forever) below:

> Run the event loop until stop() is called.

So, how to stop [**loop.run_forever()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_forever) with [**loop.stop()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.stop) in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python asyncio: event loop does not seem to stop when stop method is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093238/python-asyncio-event-loop-does-not-seem-to-stop-when-stop-method-is-called)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call **`loop.stop()`** in **`test()`** by passing **`loop`** to **`test()`** as shown below:

```py
import asyncio

async def test(loop):
    print("Test")
    loop.stop() # Here

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
                     
loop.create_task(test(loop)) # Pass "loop" to "test()"

loop.run_forever()
```